# if - else Statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I would like to ask regarding this if-else conditional statement. I've been studying this for quite some time. I am a beginner that's why I really need your advice. Why does my else doesn't work? As you can see on the console instead of showing the (Account Not Found!) it still shows Welcome there. I don't know what I'm missing.

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

String Usernames [] = { "Reyn", "Gel", "Cinds", "Jmr"};
String Passwords [] = {"Reinyy", "0815", "Eyy", "Qatar"};

System.out.print("Username :");
String username = s.nextLine();
System.out.print("Password :");
String password = s.nextLine();

boolean isExist = false;

for (int i = 0; i < Usernames.length; i++) {
    if (username.equals(Usernames[i]) &&
        password.equals(Passwords[i]));
    isExist = true;
    break;
}

if (isExist) System.out.println ("Welcome, " + username + "!");

else System.out.println ("Account Not Found!");
```

Comment: *password.equals(Passwords[i]));* Have a look at that carefully. What does `;` mean?

Comment: Yes, that pesky semicolon, `;`, is short-circuiting your if test.

Comment: [Be careful of you naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: Not related to your problem, but please don't define arrays as `String Usernames []`, although this is valid syntax, it is considered a bad practice to use. Instead, use `String[] userNames` (which also follows the normal Java convention that variables and fields start with a lowercase letter).

Comment: Thank you guys for answering my question. I'll take all of your comments as a lesson.